# Force reload of page link

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, hyperlink, reload

I have a "thank you" page upon form submittal, but when they click the link

```
<p>Please click <a href="index.html">here</a> to request additional items.</p>
```

the index page loads, however the first link in the page is unable to be clicked (it's an anchor link). I have a "data-ajax=false" attribute in the index page, and think that's what's causing the issue. What I would like is to find a parameter in the above code to force a reload of the index.html page, because if, once the link is clicked and the page loads, if I hit the refresh button, everything works as it should. If you would like to know the site itself to check it out, send me a PM. Or if you have any suggestions about simply forcing the link to reload, that'd be great too.

Thanks!
ClevelandITGuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach a click event to `<a id="gotoindex" href="#">here</a>` and instruct jQuery Mobile to reload the page:

```
$(document).on("click", "#gotoindex", function(event, ui)
{
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "index.html",
    {
        allowSamePageTransition : true,
        transition              : "none",
        showLoadMsg             : false,
        reloadPage              : true
    });
});
```

Comment: Where about should I insert the "$(document)...." code? The thankyou page currently is an .html page. Should I change it to a .php page?

Comment: I have several mailing php pages that my html forms POST to, and at the end of the php I have: if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else { echo "Success!";
header("Location: thank-you.html");
}
?>

Comment: You have to insert JavaScript code in a `<script></script>` tag just before `</body>`; PHP is not needed because that code is executed in the client browser

Comment: Excellent, I got this to work. Originally I had a separate thankyou.html page, but I was able to incorporate it into the index.html page (index.html#thankyou), and link my phpmailer success location to it. This allowed me to use your script (many thanks!) and it refreshes the index page just as I needed it to.